# Where Do I Find Exceptions a Method Throws?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the Exceptions that are thrown by `HttpClient`'s `GetAsyncString` method. I've checked the docs on MSDN but I can't seem to find what exceptions are thrown by the method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Intellisense shows them if they are stated in XML docs

Comment: Classes do not throw exceptions.

Comment: Fixed that lol. Sorry.

Comment: You'd have to look at the code, but the question makes no real sense in and of itself. Surely you aren't planning on trapping "all" of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throws `ArgumentNullException` (Assume you are talking about `GetStringAsync` here).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the [`GetStringAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The exceptions are listed in the documentation, it will thow an `ArgumentNullException` if the parameter is null.

That doesn't seem to be the entire truth, though. If you look at the example code on the documentation page for the [`HttpClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the process of making a request can also throw an `HttpRequestException`. The reason that it's not listed on the method page is probably that the method call itself will never throw it, it's thrown by the asynchronous process that does the request.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** The documentation for `GetStringAsync` only gives a partial answer to the question. Without clarification from Microsoft, you won't be able to get an official answer to your question. Unofficial answers may help now, but there will not be any guarantee that future releases of the .NET Framework (even patch releases) will preserve the precise exception behavior you observe currently.

**Long answer:**

One of the outstanding problems for the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) is the question of how exceptions are documented for asynchronous methods. Traditionally, the exception documentation only included exceptions thrown by the *synchronous* behavior of the method. Unfortunately, this leaves no place for documenting exceptions thrown during the *asynchronous* behavior of the method, i.e. the exceptions that you'd see only if you look at the [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) property of the returned `Task`, or attempt to `await` the task. The MSDN documentation for `GetStringAsync` only documents the synchronous exceptions for the method.

So you are aware of one alternative, even though it doesn't address your specific question here, see the section [Exceptions Thrown by Asynchronous Methods](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/32cc6156-3b31-4450-b209-b55fcfc0a210.htm) I wrote for a library I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you search on MSDN for the class and method it will tell you what exceptions that method with itself create, not exceptions that are external to it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.110).aspx